# Problem during isolated controller unit testing / NestJS / JestJS / Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

I would like to write unit test for my http controller with mocked service.
Main idea is to mock service and provide some mock implementation for it.

Here is my setup to do this (I will skip some imports statements and useless in our context decorators to reduce code lines amount):

**create-user.http.controller.ts:**

```js
export class CreateUserHttpController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(createUserSymbol)
    private readonly createUser: CreateUserService,
  ) {}

  @Post(appRoutes.users.root)
  async create(@Body() body: CreateUserRequest): Promise<IdResponse> {
    const command = new CreateUserCommand({
      email: body.email,
      name: body.name,
      password: body.password,
      role: 'user',
    });

    const id = await this.createUser.createUser(command);

    return new IdResponse(id.value);
  }
}
```

**create-user.http.controller.spec.ts:**

```js
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { ID } from 'src/core/value-objects/id.value-object';

import { createUserSymbol } from '../../user.providers';
import { CreateUserHttpController } from './create-user.http.controller';
import { CreateUserService } from './create-user.service';

jest.mock('./create-user.service', () => {
  return {
    CreateUserService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        createUser: () => {
          console.log('ts');
        },
      };
    }),
  };
});

describe('CreateUserHttpController', () => {
  let createUserHttpController: CreateUserHttpController;
  let createUserService: CreateUserService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CreateUserHttpController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: createUserSymbol,
          useValue: CreateUserService,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    createUserHttpController = await moduleRef.resolve(
      CreateUserHttpController,
    );
    createUserService = await moduleRef.resolve(createUserSymbol);
  });

  describe('create', () => {
    it('should call once createUser method in service', async () => {
      const expectedResult = new ID('test');

      jest
        .spyOn(createUserService, 'createUser')
        .mockResolvedValue(expectedResult);

      const result = await createUserHttpController.create({
        email: 'test@mail.ru',
        name: 'test',
        password: 'test',
      });

      expect(createUserService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

And with this setup I have an issue like this:
(*Cannot spy property because it is not a function; undefined given instead*)

[image]

I've tried to console.log mocked service instance to check if there is a 'createUser' property. And it looks like it's not there.

[image]

I've checked jest docs deeply, especially here - [jest doc for mocking non-default class exports](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports). I've spend like 6 hours and tried all available options, but result is still the same.

Also I've checked guide here - [medium guide](https://medium.com/@jackallcock97/unit-testing-with-nestjs-and-jest-a-comprehensive-tutorial-464910f6c6ba). This lucky guy seems to have identical setup and no any issues.

So, from my perspective it looks like `jest.mock` function for some reason isn't initialize mocked service with `createUser` method.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you use `moduleRef.resolve` instead of `moduleRef.get`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel resolve looks simplier :) And it's fine to get a unique instance of provider in this case I believe. Btw I've tried with `.get` and nothing changes.

Comment: `resolve` is generally for `TRANSIENT` and `REQUEST` scoped providers, and while I believe it _could_ work with `SINGLETON` it's usually better to use the proper API for it.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Agreed, I will revisit this topic deeply, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see what's going on here. In your custom provider for `createUserSymbol` you're using the mock created for `CreateUserService`, but this mock, is a factory, not a direct value, so instead of `useValue` you should use `useFactory` so that Nest ends up calling the factory function. f you remove the `jest.fn().mockImplementation()` and just look at what would be there instead you have

```js
{
  CreateUserService: () => {
    return {
      createUser: () => {
        console.log('ts');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So to get that returned object out you would need to call the function first, i.e. `CreateUserService()`, or, as  mentioned you can use `useFactory` instead and Nest will call that method for you.

---

A different option would be to forgo the `jest.mock()` entirely and just pass a custom value to Nest for mocking, like

```js
const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [CreateUserController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: createUserSymbol,
      useValue: {
        createUse: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => console.log('ts'))
      }
    }
  ],
}).compile();
```

This approach can be testing module agnostic as well, so it's easier to swap things out if for whatever reason you decide to change libraries

Comment: Thank you for a response. Do I get you right that in first scenario Im supposed to call CreateUserService constructor myself inside useFactory function? Difficulty here is that I have repo injected in service. Do I need to mock repository as well to call the constructor???

Also I was able to achieve required behaviour with jest.mock and this:

`providers: [{provide: createUserSymbol, useClass: CreateUserService,},],`

With this setup it actually calls mocked version of the function and I can easily spyOn that.

Comment: In your first scenario, it isn't a constructor. It's just a factory function. There's no `new` to be called. The beauty of passing this custom mock is that it shouldn't really depend on what the original constructor is. Because the `createUserSymbol` is mocked, that's all that should be necessary. [I have a lot of examples here if that helps](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)